# SenderEmailAddress in vba code giving path in excel

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I have designed a VBA code to retrieve the list of mails from the inbox of your outlook using the link [Retrieve maillist from outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28941582/exporting-emails-from-an-outlook-subfolder-to-excel..)

Here there is a line of code

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 5) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderEmailAddress
```

which specifies to get senders email Address but when it is stored in excel it shows  as below

```
/O=EXCHANGELABS/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=WIPRO365.ONMICROSOFT.COM-52823-C1374FA5
```

I would like to see it as **knowledge@wipro.com** mean to say in the proper email format. How to avail this option? Should I do changes at VBA code or excel.

I have tried this in many blogs still vain. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Take a look at [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941191/extract-email-address-from-outlook) it gets what you need.

Comment: @newguy "This" link really help me thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, this is multiple dot notation take to its extreme -  `Folder.Items.Item(iRow)`. This is a really bad idea, especially in a loop - each "." forces Outlook to create and return a brand new COM object. Cache Folder.Items before entering the loop, and retrieve MailItem using Items.Item(I) only once at the beginning of the loop.

That being said, what you get is a perfectly valid EX type address. Check the `MailItem.SenderEmailType` property first. If it is "EX", use MailItem.Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress (be prepared to handle nulls). Otherwise just use `MailItem.SenderEmailAddress` property.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here for how to look at the Global Address Book
[Outlook 2010 GAL with Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405567/outlook-2010-gal-with-excel-vba)

Here is a very simple implementation that converts to the smtp address for Exchange accounts.

```
Option Explicit
Dim appOL As Object
Dim oGAL As Object
Dim i
Dim oContact
Dim oUser
Dim UserIndex
Dim arrUsers(1 To 65000, 2) As String

Sub test()

End Sub
Sub Download_Outlook_Mail_To_Excel()
'Add Tools->References->"Microsoft Outlook nn.n Object Library"
'nn.n varies as per our Outlook Installation
Dim folders As Outlook.folders
Dim folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim Pst_Folder_Name
Dim MailboxName

Set appOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")


'Mailbox or PST Main Folder Name (As how it is displayed in your Outlook Session)
MailboxName = "your email address"

'Mailbox Folder or PST Folder Name (As how it is displayed in your Outlook Session)
Pst_Folder_Name = "Inbox"

Set folder = Outlook.Session.folders(MailboxName).folders(Pst_Folder_Name)
If folder = "" Then
    MsgBox "Invalid Data in Input"
    GoTo end_lbl1:
End If

'Rad Through each Mail and export the details to Excel for Email Archival
Sheets(1).Activate
Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim oAccount As Outlook.Account
Dim stringAddress
FillAddress

For iRow = 1 To folder.Items.Count
    If folder.Items.Item(iRow).Class = olMail Then
        Set mail = folder.Items.Item(iRow)
        Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 1).Select
        Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 1) = mail.SenderName
        Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 2) = mail.Subject
        Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 3) = mail.ReceivedTime
        Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 4) = mail.Size

        Select Case mail.SenderEmailType
        Case "SMTP"
            Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 5) = mail.SenderEmailAddress
        Case "EX"
            'Set oAccount = Outlook.
            stringAddress = FindAddress(mail.SenderEmailAddress)
            Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 5) = stringAddress
        End Select
    End If
    'Set oAccount = mail.SenderEmailAddress
    'Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 6) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Body
Next iRow
MsgBox "Outlook Mails Extracted to Excel"

end_lbl1:

End Sub

Function FindAddress(strAddress)
Dim address As String
For i = 1 To 65000
    If UCase(arrUsers(i, 0)) = strAddress Then
        address = arrUsers(i, 2)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
FindAddress = address
End Function

Sub FillAddress()
    Set oGAL = appOL.GetNamespace("MAPI").AddressLists("Global Address List").AddressEntries
    For i = 1 To oGAL.Count
        Set oContact = oGAL.Item(i)
        If oContact.AddressEntryUserType = 0 Then
            Set oUser = oContact.GetExchangeUser
            If Len(oUser.LastName) > 0 Then
                UserIndex = UserIndex + 1
                arrUsers(UserIndex, 0) = oUser.address
                arrUsers(UserIndex, 1) = oUser.Name
                arrUsers(UserIndex, 2) = oUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Execution is very slow. When am trying to retrieve from the sub-folder it is not identifying the subfolder and up with no result.